# Bug with irregular line-heights with a custom font in a C# WinRT project

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-runtime, custom-font

I've defined a custom font in a C# WinRT app, but it seems to have introduced a bug in how the control (a RichEditBox) sets the line height.

Basically, what is happening is that a line with either no content or exclusively white space characters is appearing slightly higher than lines that have text on them. The following image demonstrates the problem:

[image]

It's particularly noticeable when text is added to formerly blank lines above another block of text, as the other block is pushed up slightly when the line becomes shorter.

I'm calling the font like this:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="EditorBox" FontFamily="{StaticResource Cousine}" />
```

From a resource like this:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="Cousine">/Fonts/Cousine-Regular.ttf#Cousine</FontFamily>
```

This problem also seems to occur with some of the system fonts, such as Courier New, but it doesn't occur with the default font (which I think is Segoe UI Semilight).

Is there any way that I can resolve this?